# Keep counters up to date for a cached website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, memcached

Our site has counters for views, comments and likes that are displayed on article thumbnails. Those thumbnails are cached and then used in various places, often cached themselves. The issue is that as the counters increment, all these different cache fragments quickly go stale. The result is that different pages displaying the same articles will show counters with different values.

The site is made in RoR 4.2.1 and caching is done through Memcached.

What is the best way to go about maximizing caching for best performance while still keeping updated content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to do this, and it all boils down to how much optimization you need:

1. Fetch the count for page views in a separate AJAX call once the cached page has loaded. This solution should be highly compatible with your current design.
2. Cache partials instead of complete page. This means that you'll have cached copies of all partials except that for page views, and so you might need to make major changes in your code.
3. If the requests are too high, you can also write an approximation function (in js), which given past page views tells you the estimated page views, which can be displayed to end user. The base data can be refreshed every minute (or custom frequency).

Comment: Thanks Mu. I should probably have been more specific when I talked about thumbnails that there's 21 of those per page (7x3), so 21 sets of counters. Solution 1 might still put a lot of strain on the server (unless I also cache that call for a few minutes), and 2 is already being done (Russian doll style). 3 is interesting, I'll give it a try.